# Как создать ассоциативный глобальный массив?

Tags: c#, массивы

В общем как создать такой глобальный ассоциативный массив:

```
user[0]["name"] = "Alex";
user[0]["surname"] = "AlexSurname";

user[1]["name"] = "Max";
user[1]["surname"] = "MaxSurname";
```

нуб в C#, извините за нескромный вопрос*

**updated** создаваемый динамически. Это я вручную для примера ввел, может быть сколько угодно в нем элементов.

**updated** в общем пока застрял на том что не знаю как вот это:

```
GlobalUserList.Users = new List<User> { user0, user1 };
```

применить динамически. ^ т.е. ни руками вводить user0, user1, а допустим через i user[i] и пошло-поехало. ( Просто без этого **GlobalUserList** у меня глобального массива не будет, я его не смогу получить другой кнопкой )

**updated**

> создавать массив лучше вне цикла,
> работать с ним в цикле, присваивать
> свойству - после.

а если нужно создать один массив из другого?

**updated**

```
int i = 0;
User[] user = new User[100];

foreach (a in b)
{

    if (true)
    {

        i++;
        user[i] = new User();
        user[i]["name"] = Name_From_Exists_Array[i];
        user[i]["surname"] = Surname_From_Exists_Array[i];

        GlobalUserList.Users.Add(user[i]);

    }
}
```

в итоге ошибка на строке `GlobalUserList.Users.Add(user[i])`

> В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка
> на объект?

**update** [10]

```
public static class GlobalUserList // статический класс доступен в любой ...
{
    public static List<User> Users{get;set;}

    public static GlobalUserList() // UPD: это исправит вашу проблему
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

тяжело то как:

> Статические классы не могут иметь
> конструкторы экземпляров

Comment: рекомендую, настоятельно рекомендую взяться за хорошую книгу для начинающих типа Троелсона или сайта [http://simple-cs.ru/](http://simple-cs.ru/)

Comment: спс, боюсь что все книги я ни перечитаю.

Comment: >а если нужно создать один массив из другого?

я бы сделал это с помощью [LINQ Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891.aspx), но скорее всего это вызовит ещё вопросы, поэтому все рекомендации остаются в силе

Comment: ну я уже начал, так как посоветовали в ответе, мне совсем чуток остался чтобы реализовать то что я задумал.

Comment: как же это все просто в `php` было...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

создайте статический класс, в нём создаёте свойство, которое будет инкапсулировать массив другого класса, у которого перегружен индексер

```
void Main()
{
    var user0 = new User();
    user0["name"] = "Alex";
    user0["surname"] = "AlexSurname";

    var user1 = new User();
    user1["name"] = "Max";
    user1["surname"] = "MaxSurname";

    GlobalUserList.Users = new List<User>{user0, user1};

    GlobalUserList.Users[0]["name"].Dump(); // Alex
    GlobalUserList.Users[1]["surname"].Dump(); // MaxSurname

}

public class User
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _properties;

    public User()
    {
        _properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string this[string name] // перегруженный индексер
    {
        get
        {
            return _properties[name];
        }
        set
        {
            _properties[name] = value;
        }
    }
}

public static class GlobalUserList // статический класс доступен в любой точке программы
{
    public static List<User> Users{get;set;}

    static GlobalUserList() // UPD: это исправит вашу проблему, исправил
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

**UPD:** обновил с учётов новых требований

> В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект?

Comment: Разобрался. Все отлично! Я бы все 10 поставил!

Comment: то я класс не туда засунул, но я поспешил с выводами, просто что в таком случае делать если у меня массив создается динамически:

    var user0 = new User();
    user0["name"] = "Alex";
    user0["surname"] = "AlexSurname"`

я конечно все понимаю, но имя переменной **var user0** как тогда изменять? В данный момент оно просто вручную задается, а если элементов эдак 100 будет?

Comment: массивы? не?
 
    User[] users = new User[100];
    users[0] = new User()
    ...

не забываем про циклы и прочие элементарные вещи, которые описаны в любой хорошей книге, сборнике статей и прочем по C#

>это в тот же цикл засунуть надо там где и создаю массив

создавать массив лучше вне цикла, работать с ним в цикле, присваивать свойству - после.

к тому же в данном случае можно делать так:

    GlobalUserList.Users.Add(user)

- [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: эхх, что-то я опять застрял, у меня на одной кнопке создается массив, на другой просто вывести его и не могу.

Comment: особенно с этим туговато, я так понял это в тот же цикл засунуть надо там где и создаю массив?

    GlobalUserList.Users = new List<User> { user0, user1 };