# Как создать ассоциативный массив с сортировкой, быстрым поиском и удалением элементов

Tags: c#, массивы

Привожу пример из соседней темы:

```
user[0]["name"] = "Alex";
user[0]["surname"] = "AlexSurname";

user[1]["name"] = "Max";
user[1]["surname"] = "MaxSurname";
```

В нем решены вопросы создания и возможностью работы с массивом чтобы этот список просто был.
Теперь к этому мне нужно добавить поиск(по имени `user[1]["name"]`, или по значению `user[1]`) с использованием половинного деления и удаление произвольных элементов по индексу.

Исходный материал тут:
[Как создать ассоциативный глобальный массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126376/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Comment: Как вы сами пытались решить задачу? Или ждете что ее решат за вас?

Comment: Сейчас у меня все сделано дедовским способом, без сортировки и удаления элементов. Проблема в том что подобный поиск получается очень долгим, в т.ч. из-за пересборки постоянно массива без не нужных элементов. В котором к слову сто тысяч строк. В идеале мне нужен тип данных который поддерживает ассоциативные массивы и метод Sort, в поиском Find. Подобный тип данных был на Delphi TStringList и идеально подошел бы сейчас под мою задачу

Comment: Сто тысяч строк - это полная ерунда, если вы не запрашиваете элементы из неё 1000 раз в секунду, то вы можете хранить их как вам понравится. А про ассоциативный массив - то поглядите [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`SortedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) и тогда выбирайте, что из этого вам подходит больше - но я бы на них смотрел только если есть конкретные проблемы с производительностью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы вы привели конкретные примеры, что именно и как нужно искать, можно было бы дать более точный ответ. А так, почему бы не использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
var users = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

users.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
users[0]["name"] = "Alex";
users[0]["surname"] = "AlexSurname";

users.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>());
users[1]["name"] = "Max";
users[1]["surname"] = "MaxSurname";
```

Вам нужен ассоциативный массив - используйте `Dictionary`. Нужны сортировка и бинарный поиск - есть метод `List<T>.Sort` и `List<T>.BinarySearch`.