# Как ускорить бинарный поиск? или проход 400 тысяч элементов

Tags: c#, list, словари

В общем, 700 тысяч строк(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - ip) в БД
Приходит текстовый файл с ~400 тысяч актуальных, нужно в перебрать и в БД сохранить 400 тысяч актуальных, остальные 300 пометить что они не актуальны.
Все бы ничего, все работает, но такой перебор занимает 11 минут на 4Ггц камне.
Делаю так:

```
//Тут сортирую по ip, строки из БД 700 тысяч
ListCurrentBD.Sort((x, y) => x["ipWorld"].CompareTo(y["ipWorld"]));

for(int i=0; i < ipList.Count; i++)
{
    //находим индекс по компарер ipWorld
    int indS = ListCurrentBD.BinarySearch(ipList[i], new CompareripWorld());
    if (!(indS<0))
    {
        //Заносим данные, позже по этому листу обновим актуальные ip
        ListUpdateBD.Add(ipList[i]);
        //добавляем идентификатор по которому будем обновлять актуальность
        ListUpdateBD[ListUpdateBD.Count-1]["id"] = ListCurrentBD[indS]["id"];               }

       }
```

Начало вопроса [Как создать ассоциативный массив с сортировкой, быстрым поиском и удалением элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/875620/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Comment: А что представляет из себя ListCurrentBD? какой тип то?

Comment: а какой именно участок кода занимает 11 минут?

Comment: var ListCurrentBD = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

Comment: 11 минут занимает обработка всего цикла for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сгенерируем 700к + 400к случайных IP

```
Random r = new Random();

var ipAddresses = Enumerable.Range(0, 700000)
                    .Select(x => $"{r.Next(256)}.{r.Next(256)}.{r.Next(256)}.{r.Next(256)}")
                    .ToArray(); 

var validAddresses = new HashSet<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, 400000)
                .Select(x => $"{r.Next(256)}.{r.Next(256)}.{r.Next(256)}.{r.Next(256)}"));
```

Складывать результат будем в списки (можно было бы и LINQ запрос написать, но так наглядней)

```
var valids = new List<string>();
var inValids = new List<string>();
```

Обработка включения 700к адресов в 400к валидных

```
foreach(var ip in ipAddresses)
{
    if(validAddresses.Contains(ip)) valids.Add(ip);
    else inValids.Add(ip);
}
```

Вывод результата

```
Console.WriteLine($"vailds: {valids.Count}, inValids: {inValids.Count}");
```

Результат

```
vailds: 73, inValids: 699927
```

На моем не самом мощном пк - 1.5 секунды.

Comment: а если перед циклом предварительно сортировать эти 700 000 строк? перед циклом, но включая время сортировки в итоговое

Comment: @Grundy зачем сортировать?

Comment: @Grundy вместе с бесполезной сортировкой 700к записей на моей машине -  7 секунд

Comment: Тоже не пойму зачем сортировать

Comment: @tym32167, было предположение что у ТС сортировка как раз тормозит все :-)

Comment: @Grundy у автора сортировка с каким то своим компаратором + внутри цикла зачем-то стоит бинарный поиск, когда автор работает со словарями

Comment: @tym32167 Сначала я хотел написать, что при таком решении ен смогу вывести и определить идентификатор CurrentBD[indS]["id"], но можно, если в моем случае поменять искомый и проверяемый, и проверять просто на наличие, а не вытаскивать индекс объекта)

Comment: @tym32167 А если мне нужно также добавить новые ip из списка, в котором 400 тысяч,т.е. тех что нет в БД, как их отобрать?

Comment: @Grafov поменяйте местами в моем примере те, которых 700к и тех, котороых 400к :)